# PSCredentials from current user

Tags: c#, powershell, credentials

I've been a member of SO for a year and this is my first ever question!

I am currently developing a WinForms application in C# that invokes PowerShell scripts.  It is not designed to be a comprehensive handler for all of PowerShell's capabilities, but merely executes a small selection of scripts with simple, pre-agreed parameter types only.

Some of the scripts require elevated permissions to run successfully.  No problem - there seems to be at least 2 ways round this:

**1. Impersonation.**
The application performs the authorisation and invokes powershell under these credentials.  I hit a problem early on with this, in that the impersonated/elevated user may not have the permissions to invoke powershell commands on the user's local machine - as the local machine may not have the appropriate ExecutionPolicy, and the elevated user would therefore have to access the Registry to change this. I have no sway in altering permissions.  Which leads me towards:

**2. Credentials as a Variable.**
Simple. Scripts have a variable such as:

```
[PSCredential]$credential
```

which the application can supply by prompting the user for the user name and password for this account.

My question is this:  Is there a way to obtain a PSCredential object from the currently logged-in user, as some kind of default for my app?
I haven't seen anything to suggest this can be done, so if anyone can inundate me as to why this is the case, I would be glad to hear it.   It would be feasible to force the application to run as an administrator, if this is of any help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You do not need registry access to modify execution policy. You can either launch powershell.exe with a desired execution policy or initialize the hosted powershell runspace with a script that sets the desired policy for the process scope. I don't think there is way to get a credential for the current user without prompting at least once, because it is like getting the current user's password. However, you could prompt and then store the credentials in an encrypted form.

Comment: Thanks @mikez. I think this settles it - it's the best answer I will get, so feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no way to get the credential for the current user without prompting a user for their input.  For one thing, it is quite simple to obtain the clear text password from the "SecureString" password property of the `PSCredential` instance.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that You can Achieve this with System.Security.Principal class. It has static method called getCurrent(). This method return object of WindowsIdentity of currently logged in user. Try to search for this. If i will find an article i'll edit this answer

EDIT

I found an example, it's pretty straight forward(there is also a tab called code with full example - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Add-Window-Authentication-833ba913#content

EDIT v.2

```
    private WindowsIdentity GetloggedinUser() 

    { 
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser =System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();    
        return currentUser; 
    }
```

After using this method You already have retrieved an instance of currently logged user(of WindowsIdentity Type). In the link below You can see properties of WindowsIdentity Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx

I'm not familiar with powershell, but i am using this class in my company for some our private apps within the domain and it works well.

Comment: Unfortunately the example you referenced does not explain how a PSCredential instance can be obtained, which is what I'm struggling with.  It also seems to have no idea about the current user and their current domain.  I'm looking for maximum automation.

Comment: No idea about current user ? I'll answer in my question.